# Is there a value X such that new Date(X) yields the current date?

Tags: javascript, date, parameters, null

In a more general sense, I'm wondering if a value in Javascript can behave as if no variable were input, so that `new Date(whatever)` functions exactly like `new Date()`.

null doesn't do this, instead creating a Date of (I think) -1 UNIX seconds (the very end of 1969). Is there a string that would work, e.g "now"?

Comment: Why not just omit the argument?

Comment: Using `Date(undefined)` (or using a variable with the value `undefined`) would have the same effect as `Date()`.

Comment: @DonovanM No, it doesn't. Notice that OP is talking about `new Date`, not `Date`.

Comment: Ah, right. I was looking at the content of the question, not the title.

Comment: Actually that was helpful, because the "new" part might not be crucial. Thanks!

Comment: In `new Date(null)`, the value `null` is converted to `+0` so returns a Date as if called `new Date(0)`, per [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-value).

Comment: @Lenoxus—the "new part" is crucial because when Date is called as a function, any arguments are ignored and it returns a string representing the current date and time as if called `new Date().toString()`. Just read [*the spec*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
new Date(Date.now());
```

to get the current date. Typing that into the console would return (for today's date)

```
Wed Jul 12 2017 14:03:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

To clarify, Date.now() returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 at 0:00 UTC.

You can read more about Date here : [MDN: Date - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Though `Date.now()` is not a single value, it changes every millisecond and it's entirely redundant in the expression `new Date(Date.now())`.

Comment: I'm well aware. OP asked specifically for a way to get the current time by passing a variable into the Date constructor. A bit of an odd request, but hey.

Comment: I guess we all realise this is an illogical request but the OP choses to not reveal their reasons. :-(

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no single value that would instruct [`new Date(…)` with one argument](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value) to use the current time. However, you can call `Date.now()` or `new Date()` to get the current time, and then pass that to the constructor, which will return a new `Date` instance with that time.

Comment: Well, if `Date.now()` is considered a "single value" then `new Date(Date())` is less to type and equivalent in functionality. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I don't consider it a single value, as `Date.now()` can produce many different values. Yes, passing the result of `Date()` would work as well, but the roundtrip (formatting+parsing) through string representation is much more expensive.